# HttpURLConnection returns response as FileNotFoundException (404) instead of 401

Tags: java, android, spring, http

My application uses `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to get a file input stream. Server is using spring boot framework of java. When authentication token is expired spring boot filter is throwing SecurityException & we are setting response code as 401 as follows (Spring boot server side ):

```
catch (ExpiredJwtException eje) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```

But at android side we are getting exception FileNotFoundException which represents the 404 & response code as -1. Why am I not able to get the response code as 401 ?

Following code I am using to check the response code (Android side):

```
urlConnection.connect();

                if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {

                }

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: I think u have get exception because of urlConnection.getInputStream().

Comment: If your urlConnection.getResponseCode() is 401 or 404 the u have to use urlConnection.getErrorStream();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code.

```
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = null;
if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
}else
{
    inputStream =  urlConnection.getErrorStream()
}
```